# Spark Sql udf with variable number of parameters

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I want a concat function for Spark Sql.
I have written a udf as

```
sqlContext.udf.register("CONCAT",(args:String*)=>{
 String out=""
 for(arg<-args)
  {
    out+=arg
  }
 out
})

sqlContext.sql("select col1,col2,CONCAT(col1,col2) from testtable")
```

but this udf is not working and I am getting an exception.
If I try with fixed number of parameters then it works.
I am using spark 1.3.1 and scala 2.10.5.

Has anyone faced this issue or knows a solution for this?

Comment: Can you provide the exception in the question?

Answer (score 4):

You can do this using the `struct` function like following:

```
val myUDF = udf {
  (r: Row) => r.toSeq.map(...) // the "r" row contains your arguments
}
val df = ....
df.select(col("col1"), myUDF(struct(col("col2"), col("col3"), col("col4"), ...)))
```

Answer (score 2):

If all you want is to concatenate columns using raw SQL there is no need for a custom UDF at all. `CONCAT` function is already there:

```
val df = sc.parallelize(List(("a", "b", "c"))).toDF("x", "y", "z")
df.registerTempTable("df")
sqlContext.sql("SELECT CONCAT(x, y, z) AS xyz FROM df").show

// +---+
// |xyz|
// +---+
// |abc|
// +---+
```

Since 1.5.0 you can use `concat` / `concat_ws` functions directly:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{concat, concat_ws}

df.select(concat_ws("-", $"x", $"y", $"z").alias("x-y-z")).show
// +-----+
// |x-y-z|
// +-----+
// |a-b-c|
// +-----+

df.select(concat($"x", $"y", $"z").alias("xyz")).show

// +---+
// |xyz|
// +---+
// |abc|
// +---+
```

See also [Spark UDF with varargs](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33151866/1560062)