# Spark UDF with varargs

Tags: scala, apache-spark, udf

Is it an only option to list all the arguments up to 22 as shown in documentation?

https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.5.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.UDFRegistration

Anyone figured out how to do something similar to this?

```
sc.udf.register("func", (s: String*) => s......
```

(writing custom concat function that skips nulls, had to 2 arguments at the time)

Thanks

Answer (score 40, accepted):

UDFs don't support varargs* but you can pass an arbitrary number of columns wrapped using an `array` function:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{udf, array, lit}

val myConcatFunc = (xs: Seq[Any], sep: String) => 
  xs.filter(_ != null).mkString(sep)

val myConcat = udf(myConcatFunc)
```

An example usage:

```
val  df = sc.parallelize(Seq(
  (null, "a", "b", "c"), ("d", null, null, "e")
)).toDF("x1", "x2", "x3", "x4")

val cols = array($"x1", $"x2", $"x3", $"x4")
val sep = lit("-")

df.select(myConcat(cols, sep).alias("concatenated")).show

// +------------+
// |concatenated|
// +------------+
// |       a-b-c|
// |         d-e|
// +------------+
```

With raw SQL:

```
df.registerTempTable("df")
sqlContext.udf.register("myConcat", myConcatFunc)

sqlContext.sql(
    "SELECT myConcat(array(x1, x2, x4), '.') AS concatenated FROM df"
).show

// +------------+
// |concatenated|
// +------------+
// |         a.c|
// |         d.e|
// +------------+
```

A slightly more complicated approach is not use UDF at all and compose SQL expressions with something roughly like this:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.Column

def myConcatExpr(sep: String, cols: Column*) = regexp_replace(concat(
  cols.foldLeft(lit(""))(
    (acc, c) => when(c.isNotNull, concat(acc, c, lit(sep))).otherwise(acc)
  )
), s"($sep)?$$", "") 

df.select(
  myConcatExpr("-", $"x1", $"x2", $"x3", $"x4").alias("concatenated")
).show
// +------------+
// |concatenated|
// +------------+
// |       a-b-c|
// |         d-e|
// +------------+
```

but I doubt it is worth the effort unless you work with PySpark.

---

* If you pass a function using varargs it will be stripped from all the syntactic sugar and resulting UDF will expect an `ArrayType`. For example:

```
def f(s: String*) = s.mkString
udf(f _)
```

will be of type:

```
UserDefinedFunction(<function1>,StringType,List(ArrayType(StringType,true)))
```

Comment: No, unless you pass column names explicitly as literals.

Comment: Hey thanks, can you please share the syntax for the same

Comment: @Kalpesh `array(df.columns.map(c => struct(lit(c), col(c)): _*)` -> `udf(xs: Seq[Row] => ???)`.

Comment: Pay attention to write array and not Array when calling the function