# Scala: variadic UDF

Tags: scala, udf

I have a DataFrame with a many columns.
I also have a function

```
def getFeatureVector(features:Array[String]) : Vector
```

that is fairly complex, but takes some strings and returns a spark MLlib vector.

Now, I want to look at some columns in the DF (I don't know which beforehand), pass them to getFeatureVector, and add a new column containing the resulting vectors.

I have access to an array of the columns I want to use, and I wrote a function that casts it to string, and makes an array column:

```
val colNamesToEncode = Array("col1", "col2", "col3", "col4")
def getColsToEncode:Column = {
    val cols = colNamesToEncode.map(x => col(x).cast("string"))
    array(cols:_*)
}
```

Finally, I try to make a udf and apply it to the DF:

```
val encoderUDF = udf(getFeatureVector _)
val cols = getColsToEncode()
data.withColumn(featuresColName,encoderUDF(cols))
```

but when I run that, I get java.lang.RuntimeException: Unsupported literal type class scala.runtime.BoxedUnit ()

How can I apply to function to the DF?

PS: I was using this answer ([Spark UDF with varargs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33151866/spark-udf-with-varargs)) as a guide while writing my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove `()` from the below line, that resolved the error.

From `val cols = getColsToEncode()`

To

```
val cols = getColsToEncode
```

Answer (score 0):

You can directly pass the function into the udf function.

```
val colNamesToEncode = Array("col1", "col2", "col3", "col4")
def getColsToEncode:Column = {
val cols = colNamesToEncode.map(x => col(x).cast("string"))
array(cols:_*)
}

val encoderUDF = udf(getFeatureVector _)
data.withColumn(featuresColName,encoderUDF(getColsToEncode))
```