# How to register variable length function in spark sql

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I want to register a variable length function in spark sql with following code，

```
ssc.udf.register("md5", (a: String*) => {
  a.foldLeft(0)((x: Int, y: String) => x + y.length)
})
```

But it looks that it is not supported in this way，could someone help how to register a variable length function in spark sql，
Thanks！

Comment: This is not possible, but there could be a workaround. Take a look at [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33151866/spark-udf-with-varargs)

Comment: Thanks @BhashitParikh

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spark UDF with varargs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33151866/spark-udf-with-varargs).