# Pivot on multiple columns dynamically in Spark Dataframe

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, pivot

This is what I am using for two pivot column in a Dataframe where I am concatenating two columns and then doing the transpose.

```
// Define a udf to concatenate two passed in string values
val concat = udf( (first: String, second: String) => { first + " " + second } )

def main (args: Array[String]) {

    // pivot using concatenated column
    domainDF.withColumn("combColumn", concat($"col1",$"col2"))
      .groupBy("someCol").pivot("combColumn").agg(count).show()

  }
```

My requirement is make this functionality generic, so any number of columns can be passed as variable argument for concatenation.
Can anyone provide any solution for the requirement?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the built-in concatination function instead, it allows for a variable number of input columns. See the [documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html#concat-org.apache.spark.sql.Column...-).

In this case, you can do:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

domainDF.withColumn("combColumn", concat(Seq($"col1", $"col2"):_*))
  .groupBy("someCol").pivot("combColumn").agg(count)
```

If you want to use a separator between the column values, use `concat_ws`. For example, to use a space: `concat_ws(" ", Seq(...))`.

---

If you need to use an `UDF` due to other concerns, it's possible to use a variable number of arguments by wrapping them in an array, see: [Spark UDF with varargs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33151866/spark-udf-with-varargs)

Comment: Thanks for your reply.. Just one thing I need to check, as what is the default seperator here in concat? In my case I am using single space between two columns.

Comment: concat_ws is working absolutely fine with first parameter as seperator like.. concat_ws(" ",pivotColumn map col:_*).

Comment: @AB: As you noted `concat` will not use any separator and `concat_ws` should be used where that is wanted. I added this information to the answer as well. :)